# Link not working on a Div on Ipad only - any other device/browsers works 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

sorry if asking this question in wrong place.

I have a web page (asp.net / vb) and each section of the web page is built in divs inside a bootstrap grid.

Using the code behind, I am adding onclick events to each bunch of div's to do certain things.  Every single div/onclick works on the page apart from just one that will only work if I set the div to something like 100 pixels deep.

I am in safari.

I have tried allsorts - binding with jquery click/tap etc but nothing apart from making the div really large.

I dont understand how only this one div could cause problems.

This text box wont let me paste html in to show.

If anyone could suggest anything I would be really grateful!

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely facing an issue where you've got one element covering up another. Check to make sure that you don't have any other div's that are too wide and happen to be covering your link on the iPad. This would explain why when you move it to 100 pixels deep it works.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I have checked that and the section that doesnt work is not created html/div than any different from the ones that work.  i just added a jquery tap and click and every now and again it shows the alert i have told it to on each function.

Comment: When you say "every now and again it shows the alert" I still immediately think it must be partially covered, however without seeing a code snippet of some kind it may be difficult to ascertain the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After further checking it was an image/div causing the issue.  I have marked your answer as the working one.